# UINavigationBar background shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

I'm experiencing a weird problem when I segue to a UIViewController I've made. ViewController B (the one I segue to) has a UIView that slides down using the TransitionCoordinator and constraints, but it shows a grey shadow at the right, like so:

[image]

Once the segue is completely done, it goes back to translucent and displays the blue UIView through the UINavigationBar with a nice blur.

This grey shadow is most likely due to a UIToolBar and UISegmentedControl within that toolbar on the UITableViewController that I segue from. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm using this code together with my UIToolBar:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

I've tried to use a TransitionCoordinator to fade out the UIToolBar using it's alpha property, but without success. I've also visited other similar questions on SO, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

The strange thing is that it sometimes work as it should, but I can't figure out why it doesn't always happen nor how to completely remove it.

**view hierarchy:**

Xcode view hierarchy:

[image]

View hierarchy in list:

[image]

Transparent navigationBar:

[image]

**More information:**

- Pulling down the UITableView also displays this, how can I attach the UIToolbar? Looks like the delegate methods isn't working propery.
- When adding a new item to the list, the problem disappears until I restart the root ViewController in the navigation hierarchy

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)removeShadowLineFromNavBar{
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
        if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [view2 removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
}
```

That line is a `UIImageView` inside UINavigationBar as a subview. Going through subviews you can remove it just like any other view from its super view.

Comment: I'm seeing the same effect on a blurred (normal) UIToolBar at the bottom of the destination ViewController. Do you think this will fix that as well? Trying later today

Comment: That code removed the line but I'm still getting that grey shadow problem. I also need a way of restoring this UIImageView shadow line because I need it on other ViewControllers in the same navigation stack